# Strange issue while running batch file with process builder in java

Tags: java, process, batch-file, processbuilder

I have the following java code snippet which runs a batch file( renames a file depending on a flag ). This code works properly. But when i comment the line `while( isRunning(p) ) {}` then it doesn't work. Can anyone give any reason for that ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(  fileManipulatorScriptLocation, "Rename_File", "a.txt", "b.txt" );
        pb.directory( new File(targetDirectory) );
        Process p = pb.start();
        while( isRunning(p) ) {}
    }

    public static boolean isRunning(Process process) {
        try {
            process.exitValue();
            return false;
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Else the Java process will be ended, because the main method has been finished, along with its child processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the busy-waiting infinite loop, use `Process#waitFor`. Why it doesn't work: your parent process (Java) dies immediately, dragging the child process with it.

Answer (score 0):

`isRunning()` checks for `Process#exitValue()`.

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29):

Returns the exit value for the subprocess.

**Returns**:
the exit value of the subprocess represented by this Process object. by convention, the value 0 indicates normal termination.

**Throws**:
IllegalThreadStateException - if the subprocess represented by this Process object has not yet terminated.

Means, that `IllegalThreadStateException` is thrown inside `isRunning()` method if process is still running, but that exceptin is catched, so method return `true`, otherwise `exitValue()` return process exist value and `isRunning` method return `false` which breaks `while` loop.